# Create a shortcut to toggle the Outline view in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, keymapping

I've successfully created a key shortcut for outline.focus which displays the Outline panel. I'm looking for toggle behaviour.

**Existing**:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+o",
    "command": "outline.focus",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```

Is it possible??

Comment: You should clarify in the question whether you are talking about toggling between the outline view and the editor focus  or toggling the outline view tree open or closed once the outline view is focused.

Answer (score 4):

There is a new `outline` command: `outline.collapseItems` which might be helpful here depending on what you are trying to do.  See [v1.73 vNext release notes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_73.md#outline-default-collapse-state):

> #### Outline default collapse state
>
> There is a new setting `outline.collapseItems` that controls the
> default collapse state of outline items. The default value is `false`
> which means that outline items are expanded by default. Set it to
> `true` to have outline items collapsed by default. This setting can be
> set per language and also works for notebooks.

---

This will switch focus to the outline view and collapse all opened tree items in the outline view.

[ Handy option: "**Follow Cursor**" option in the Options View (click the `...` for the options).]

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+alt+o",
  "command": "list.collapseAll",   // Ctrl+LeftArrow also does this
                                   // Space will open the current tree item
                                   // left/right arrows will open/close item
  "when": "outline.active"
},

{
  "key": "ctrl+alt+o",
  "command": "outline.focus",
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
},
```

So clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> once shifts focus to the Outline view and clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> a second time collapses all opened items.  There is no `list.expandAll` command for some reason so you can't toggle those.

These could be combined into a single macro command if you wish, so there would be just one key combo to hit to focus the Outline view and collapse all.  Let me know if you want to see that.

Comment: yeah, I have given up and requested a feature and more commands (specially toggle). if I can select Collapse All in the Outline panel, it would be great to do it with commands

Comment: I changed the answer, assuming you wanted to `toggle` between collapsed/open outline tree items - not toggle between the outline view and editor view.  If you wanted the later, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

With this you should be able to toggle between the outline view and the editor group to the right.

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+o",
     "command": "workbench.action.focusRightGroup", 
     "when": "outline.active"
},
{
     "key": "ctrl+alt+o",
     "command": "outline.focus",
     "when": "editorTextFocus"
,
```

You can also substitute any of the other focus editor group type of commands, i.e. first group: `workbench.action.focusFirstEditorGroup`.

However, you can already do this using the outline focus binding above and then hitting the default editor group binding without defining the toggle.

Answer (score 1):

In addition of outline focus, you also have, with VSCode 1.47, June 2020, the ability to add **basic keybinding for focusing on an element in outline panel** ([PR 91799](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/91799) for [issue 90732](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/90732))

It will be with the setting `list.selectAndPreserveFocus`

See:

> ### "[Select and keep focus in a list view](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/4762c7285c385d1ebd5076b5414a7874117c48aa/release-notes/v1_47.md#select-and-keep-focus-in-a-list-view)"
>
> There is a new command, `list.selectAndPreserveFocus`, which lets you select an item from a list, while keeping focus in that list.
> This can be helpful if you want to select multiple files from a list, such as the File Explorer, without having focus go to the file editor.
>
> The command is not bound to any keyboard shortcut by default, but you can add your own keybinding:
>
> ```
> {
>   "key"    : "ctrl+o",
>   "command": "list.selectAndPreserveFocus"
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Settings Cycler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hoovercj.vscode-settings-cycler) extension by Cody Hoover.